# Comparing the Goodness of fit of two polytomous set of items not nested

Tags: factor-analysis, goodness-of-fit, item-response-theory

I'm working on two identical set of items that only differ in their frequency-of-occurence dimension (in the first is max.7 while in the second is max.4). They are both fit with the Generalised partial credit model. I would like to understand if the scale has a better fit with 7 categories or with 4. Is there a test I could use?

Comment: could you please share a little more information, please?  Have the scales been chosen from the literature in your field, with a comparable cohort of subjects?  Have you collected data and now wish to compare?  If you have collected the data, what is the sample size, and of more concern, how many times was each of the seven or four categories selected?  Thanks!